# HTML/CSS: Responsively transpose a table when it no longer fits on screen

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a need to display something like this:

```
label | B1 | B2 | ... | BN
label | B1 | B2 | ... | BN
```

BX is a button. I need these to line up like a table. And N depends on the program contents. I can't know this ahead of time. Often it will be small like 3, but it might be large like 11. And on a mobile screen, there isn't room for the label and the 11 buttons horizontally.

So when the row no longer fits the screen, I need to transpose this to display it like:

```
label | label
  B1  |  B1
  B1  |  B1
   :     :
  B1  |  B1
```

I was looking at CSS grid but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to automatically transpose.

Is there a way with CSS?